# Back-propagation KL-divergence for training “one level neural network”

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, stanford-nlp

I am new in machine-learning and python, I had read the paper http://nlp.stanford.edu/~socherr/EMNLP2013_RNTN.pdf,
I should use Back-propagation KL-divergence for training “one level neural network” and every one say that it standard technical task, but I have no idea how to do it.

I hope that some one could help me. I have a L matrix (25x1000) (I have 10000 words each word is represent by 25 bits) I map each word to one of 5 classes {vary negative,negative, neutral,positive,vary positive} I need to train matrix Ws(5x25) by using KL-divergence for following result

Cy = softmax(Ws * y)

- y a bit's vector (25x1) in L, that  represents a word for ex: (010001011..0)
- Cy vector(5x1), if "y" belong to class i (i=1..5) then bit i in vector Cy is 1     and all other bits are 0. for ex work is positive, then the vector is (00010)

I know that after the training process will end both matrix (Ws and L) will be changed.

I would be grateful if someone could give me a link for tutorials(or explain) how to use Back-propagation KL-divergence for training.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want somebody to do your work for you? Or, reformulate the whole paper? Ask concrete questions, as of now your post is too broad and vague.

Comment: I want to understend how to use  Back-propagation KL-divergence for training my model. I know that while training process matrix Ws and L should be change. I would be grateful if some one can give a link for good tutorials.

Comment: I found the following link http://halfbakedmaker.org/?p=5002&cpage=1#comment-191684, but it hard to understand what should I do.